# python string format without {}

Tags: python, string, format

Case 1:

`'{} is good'.format('This')`

Output:   `This is good.`

Case 2:   `'is good'.format('This')`

Output:  `is good`

Can I use Case 2 ? string does not contain `{}` . but I use `format()`

The reason I ask is I want to assign value only for the thing containing `{}`

```
m = ["{} is good", "{} is bad", "all are normal"]
for loop m
    m[index].format("AA")
```

Anyway I found it worked . But I have to know it is right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more of a subjective question. I would argue that its ok following the principle of [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing): If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably is a duck.

If you are looping through an array of strings and they all have the format() method, then just assume they all have something to be formated and format it.